# update inventory in shopify with PHP shopify_call

Tags: php, json, curl, shopify-api

I am making an API for Shopify with PHP, I want to update `inventory_quantity` of a product, this is my product in JSON

```
 "variants": [
    {
      "id": 1234567890123,
      "product_id": 9876543210987,
      "title": "25",
      "price": "111.00",
      "sku": "000003",
      "position": 1,
      "inventory_policy": "deny",
      "compare_at_price": "123.00",
      "fulfillment_service": "manual",
      "inventory_management": "shopify",
      "option1": "25",
      "option2": null,
      "option3": null,
      "created_at": "2020-01-01T11:35:46-05:00",
      "updated_at": "2021-01-02T15:25:14-05:00",
      "taxable": true,
      "barcode": "",
      "grams": 0,
      "image_id": null,
      "weight": 0.0,
      "weight_unit": "kg",
      "inventory_item_id": 54789632568754,
      "inventory_quantity": 1,
      "old_inventory_quantity": 1,
      "requires_shipping": true,
      "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/1234567890123"
    }
  ]
```

and I'm using the following code in PHP, but it doesn't work for me

```
    $my_location_id = 00000000001;
    $array = array(
                "variant" =>
                  array(
                      "location_id" => $my_location_id,
                     "inventory_item_id" => 39987147145391,
                     "inventory_quantity" => 13
                )
            );

    $my_tocket = "shpat_5abcdfghyisjdjdjdjdjskdj123456a";

    $my_shop   = "mi_tiendita_shopyfy.com";

    $products  = shopify_call($my_tocket,$shop_url,"/admin/api/2020- 
    10/inventory_levels/adjust.json",$array,"PUT");
```

I don't know if the instruction is correct, or what I'm doing wrong.

I wish you could help me.

Regards.

Comment: In what specific way does it not work? Do you get error messages?

Comment: The strange thing is that it does not throw an error, but it does not execute the changes either.
I do not know if it is the correct way to update the inventory of a product.
Regards.

Comment: I just observed that if I use the POST method it returns the following:

{"errors":{"inventory_item_id":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

What method should I use, POST or PUT ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://[API Key]:[Access Token]@[store].myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/inventory_levels/adjust.json',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "location_id": "68347298006",
    "inventory_item_id": "45597543170262",
    "available_adjustment": 10
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token: [Access Token]'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

This sum the inventory.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.